# Calculate variable name for View Scope in EditBox control

Tags: xpages

Is it possible to calculate the variable name for the ViewScpe of a EditBox control?

The Edit Box control resides in a custom control that is re-used several times on an XPage.

```
<xp:inputText id="inpValidDate"
    value="#{viewScope.valid}">
</xp:inputText>
```

I would like to use something as followed:

```
value="${viewScope[#{'compositeData.type'}]}"
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

viewScope is just a variable that is a Java Map. You can use the **viewScope.get("name of entry like compositeData.whatever")** method to get the value stored in the map entry. (Jesse's code does the same thing without using the get).
https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Map.html

However, you will need to make sure it is initialized maybe in the beforePageLoad? That is probably why you see a null.

Answer (score 2):

If it's always going to be a property inside `viewScope` like that, you can add a custom property like "propName" and set the binding to:

`<xp:inputText value="#{viewScope[compositeData.propName]}"/>`

Comment: the outcome/value of the viewScope becomes null when I print  it to the console :-?